# Force table width to text column width

Tags: tables, width

seems like an easy problem, but I'm really a newbie to LaTeX and cannot come up with solution even with some QAs on this forum I found. Can you please help?
As the picture shows, the table is wider than the text column and collides with the other column. I understand the text in the table is too long, but is there a simple way to force the table to be same width as the text and wrap the text into two lines in the same table row without using different packages?[image]

```
\usepackage[table]{hypcap}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|l}
        Parameter & Value & Units & Description\\
\toprule \midrule
        E & 200 & GPa & Young's modulus\\
        $f_{c}$ & 30 & MPa & Ultimate compressive strength\\
        $\varepsilon_{t0}$ & 805 $\cdot 10^{-4}$ & - & Initial threshold of damage for $\varepsilon_t$\\ 
\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{a}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Use a `table*` environment. Can you provide some feedback on what happens?

Comment: @Werner yes, i have tried that, but the table* environment expands the table along full page width, not respecting the text columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a different package, I don't know how to do this automatically (but I have added the missing package **booktabs** from your code in order to use the `\toprule` and `\midrule` from your code).

You could use the `p{<length>}` column specification to give to your last column a width. You need to find the value for the length with trials and errors (in this code, I have expand the size from 2cm until I obtain a *overfull hbox* warning; in this particular example, I got a warning with the value `2.5cm`, but not with the value `2.49cm`).

I have removed the **hypcap** package, not relevant here, and added **lipsum** for filling the page with text.

In this code, I have also added explicitly the `letterpaper` paper format in the document class, because the value to use for the type `p` column depend on the width of the page, and by default for some Europeans users, it's the `a4paper` format when no paper format is explicitly given.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|p{2.49cm}}
        Parameter & Value & Units & Description\\
\toprule \midrule
        E & 200 & GPa & Young's modulus\\
        $f_{c}$ & 30 & MPa & Ultimate compressive strength\\
        $\varepsilon_{t0}$ & 805 $\cdot 10^{-4}$ & - & Initial threshold of damage for $\varepsilon_t$\\ 
\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{a}
\end{table}

\lipsum[8-14]
\end{document}
```

With the original `{c|c|c|l}` tabular specification:
[image]

With the `{c|c|c|p{2.49cm}}` tabular specification:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Welcome to TeX:SE!
- Please, next time instead code fragment provide MWE (Minimal Working Example). Now we had to guessing about document class and (by it) defined page layout. Both influence on table formatting
- For your table I would emplox `tabularray` package with libraries/packages `booktabs`, `siunitx` and `ragged2e`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec={@{} c Q[c,si={table-format=3.0}] Q[c,si] X[j, appto=\RaggedRight] @{}},
             cell{3-Z}{1} = {mode=math},
             cell{1,Z}{2,3}  = {guard}
             }
    \toprule
Parameter   & Value & Units & Description\\
    \midrule
E           & 200   & \unit{\giga\pascal} 
                            & Young's modulus\\
f_{c}       & 30    & \unit{\mega\pascal} 
                            & Ultimate compressive strength\\
\varepsilon_{t_0}
            & \num{805E-4}
                    & --    & Initial threshold of damage for $\varepsilon_t$   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{a}
\label{tab:?}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]